# How to work with a table inside a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has the counts of "Yes", "No" and "-" (no answer) for survey questions for each state. The counts are saved in the cells of the data frame as a table with named columns ("-", "N", "Y") and I'm having some trouble understanding how I can programmatically perform a function for all columns.

Basically what I want to do is I want to get the percentage of "Y" for each cell.

```
usfarmersmarkets <- read_csv("https://apps.ams.usda.gov/FarmersMarketsExport/ExcelExport.aspx")
usfm <- usfarmersmarkets[c(2, 9:11,21, 22,  24:58)]
testing <- aggregate(usfm[,7:41], list(usfm$State), table)
```

This is an example of what I would like to do but for all columns not just $Credit and down all the rows not just "California". Maybe I could save the output as a list or dataframe.

```
testing[testing$Group.1 == "California",]$Credit$'05'[2] /
sum(testing[testing$Group.1 == "California",]$Credit$'05') *100

       Y 
50.06536


The dataframe has this general format
|Group.1     Credit        WIC           WICCash        ...
|Alabama    c(105, 39)    c(134, 10)    c(140, 4)       ...
|Alaska     c(20, 18)     38            c(30, 8)        ...
|Arizona    c(28, 69)     c(62, 35)     c(60, 37)       ...
|Arkansas   c(69, 33)     c(81, 21)     c(92, 10)       ...
|California 382:383       c(403, 362)   c(385, 19, 361) ...
|...
```

As you might have noticed, the cells contain 1 to 3 different values. If the cell has 1 value, it's most likely all "No"s. If it has 2 values it's most likely the first number is the "No"s and the second is the "Yes"s. If it has 3 values it's most likely that the first number is the "-"s, the second the "No"s and the third the "Yes"s.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also I'm pretty new to R so sorry if my terminology is off feel free to correct me on anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is with dplyr and tidyr. These are great tools to learn if you're picking up R because they provide really powerful ways of thinking about data manipulation. In this case I transform the data from a wide format to a long format, then do a grouped operation to count the proportion of Y's, then turn it back into wide data for the final table:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

usfm %>% 
  gather(var, value, Credit:WildHarvested) %>% 
  group_by(State, var) %>% 
  summarise(prop_Y = sum(value == "Y") / n()) %>% 
  spread(var, prop_Y)
```

There are other ways to do the job, like applying a function to each column with `lapply`, but I think dplyr is probably the easiest thing to pick up and most powerful down the road.

Comment: this works perfectly thanks so much. I will have to play with dplyr and tidyr more. I was coming at this problem all wrong apparently. Thanks again!

Comment: I think it's more that you were just experiencing the pain that dplyr and tidyr were developed to alleviate. The big advantage of the packages is that help you develop a great mental model for what your next steps might be in getting from where your data is at to where you want it to be. I'd recommend Hadley's book here: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html lots of other great stuff about the R language in that book.

Comment: oh fantastic. this will be great summer reading, much appreciated